# jquery .load function, cache failure in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, load

I am using the jquery ".load" functin to delay the "fadeIn" of pictures, till they are loaded.
However it is working fine in all browsers, just IE is making trouble - it is the cache... so far I understood the problem... but how to solve it? Is there a plugin to solve this problem?

here a code example:

```
// this is the user thumbnail, which will be loaded from the database, with a random number as filename.
if (thumb_medium == '1') {  

    // create picture link.
    var pic = Math.floor( Math.random() * (1000000) );
    var image_link = "image/image_show.php?id=" + id + "&element=image_profile_thumb_medium" + "&pic=" + pic + '.jpg';

    // write the picture link to the src attr.
    $('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).attr('src', image_link); 
}
else {

    // male image - if there is no user picture in the database.
    if (gender == 'male') { var image_link = "pic/icons/male_128_128.png" };

    // female image - if there is no user picture in the database.
    if (gender == 'female') { var image_link = "pic/icons/female_128_128.png" };

    // write the link to the src attr.
    $('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).attr('src', image_link); 
}


// when the loading process of the picture is finished a fadeIn happens - this makes problems in IE, but just with the male and female image, which get cached from IE.
$('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).load(function() { $('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).fadeIn(250) });
```

In this example, the male and female image are getting cached by IE and the next time they get loaded they mey not appear!..

what is the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a timestamp to the image url. Try this

```
if (thumb_medium == '1') {  

    // create picture link.
    var pic = Math.floor( Math.random() * (1000000) );
    var image_link = "image/image_show.php?id=" + id + "&element=image_profile_thumb_medium" + "&pic=" + pic + '.jpg';

    // write the picture link to the src attr.
    $('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).attr('src', image_link + "&t=" + (new Date()).getTime()); 
}
else {

    // male image - if there is no user picture in the database.
    if (gender == 'male') { var image_link = "pic/icons/male_128_128.png" };

    // female image - if there is no user picture in the database.
    if (gender == 'female') { var image_link = "pic/icons/female_128_128.png" };

    // write the link to the src attr.
    $('#brpr_list_thumb_' + tuple).attr('src', image_link + "?t=" + (new Date()).getTime()); 
}
```

Comment: that was my thaught too - and in fact I am solving this problem that way with the images I load from the database... but how can I add a timestamp to this link pic/icons/male_128_128.png adding something to this link would lead to a not existing image?! or do I understand this totally wrong

Comment: Look in my answer I have already added the timestamp to the image you are referring to and it will work fine without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

IE is super helpful and caches ajax returns by default!

If you'd like to have sane responses you could instead manually set all your ajax requests to be uncached. Put this at the top of your script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```